# My left rear tire looks kind of flat

Tags: safety

My left rear tire looks kind of flat but no bubble after I spun out into shoulder during rainstorm. Is it dangerous to keep driving on it?

Comment: Depends on how flat it is. Are you able to fill it up? Does it hold air? Is the tire or rim visibly damaged? Do you have a picture? -- The more flat it is, the more undesired stress and flexing happens to the sidewall.

Comment: Use a tire pressure gauge to determine if and how much air the tire is loosing. A tire can loose half it's pressure and still "look" normal, but a tire that is down 10% on it's pressure will already wear unevenly. The $1 tire gauges are just as good as the $10 ones for this.